# Simulating mouse clicks at specific screen coordinates

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, user-interface

I would like to be able to bind some keys to mouse clicks done in specific locations. For example: when I press F1 I should get a left mouse click at coordinates 300x350, F2 at 600x350 and so on. Even better if this could be bound to a specific window application so that coordinates could be relative to it instead of the base desktop.

Is there a software which allows this?

**ADDITION:**

Ok autohotkey is great but I have problems with my particular setup. Quoting my comment below:

> I'm using it with an old game (championship manager 01/02) which runs in windowed mode (and I have to set win98 compatibility for it to run): I can get the mouse to move but no click goes to the application

I have read [this FAQ](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#games) but it didn't help, this is the script I tried:

```
SendMode Play
SetKeyDelay, 0, 50, Play

F1::Click 42, 191
F2::ControlSend ahk_class main, Click, Championship Manager 01/02
```

Still no luck: pointer moves but no click goes through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.autohotkey.com/ (and its clones) provide such feature. you want to use especially the "[Click](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm)"-Command:

> Clicks a mouse button at the specified coordinates. It can also hold down a mouse button, turn the mouse wheel, or move the mouse.

Comment: That seems perfect but I have one issue: I'm using it with an old game (championship manager 01/02) which runs in windowed mode (and I have to set win98 compatibility for it to run): I can get the mouse to move but no click goes to the application; it clicks fine in other windows. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

```
SendMode Play
SetKeyDelay, 0, 0, Play

F1::Click 42, 131
F2::ControlSend ahk_class main, Click, Championship Manager 01/02
return
```

Comment: You don’t need `Return` for single-line hotkeys.

Answer (score 1):

Coordinates are relative to the active window by default, but you can specifically set it as well. You can use different commands to achieve the app-specific behavior you want. In your case, I would recommend the `#` version of `IfWinActive`; it makes it so that the hotkeys only exist for the target window and simplifies the code.

---

Have you confirmed that you are accessing the correct window? Does the program’s titlebar actually say *exactly* `Championship Manager 01/02`? Try a test with a simple script to verify:

```
#IfWinActive, Championship Manager 01/02
  F1::MsgBox Yup; correct window.
#IfWinActive
```

By default, you need to match the text of the target window’s titlebar exactly, but you can use a different matching mode:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 1 ; Match the start of the Window’s titlebar ; easier but more false-matches
e.g.: Championship Manager         matches

SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; Match any part of the titlebar; easiest but most false-matches
e.g.: ship Man                     matches

SetTitleMatchMode, 3 ; Match the titlebar of the Window exactly; most restrictive but fewer false-matches
e.g.: Championship Manager 01/02   matches
```

---

There are numerous ways to emulate a mouse-click. Try each one until you find one that works for your program. You can [specify the mode](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SendMode.htm) for the `Click` command and the generic `Send` command (which default to *Event*), or you can specify the mode explicitly (*Play* is recommended for stubborn programs and games):

```
Send      Click 42,191   ; defaults to Event
SendPlay  Click 42,191
SendInput Click 42,191
SendEvent Click 42,191

SendMode  Input
Send      Click 42,191   ; uses Input mode
SendMode  Play
Send      Click 42,191   ; uses Play mode
SendMode  Event
Send      Click 42,191   ; back to Event mode
```

---

Instead of sending a mouse-click, you could try sending a left-mouse-button, but first you need to move the cursor manually:

```
MouseMove 42,191,0 ; Immediately move the cursor relative to the active window
Send LButton       ; Left-click
```

---

As for [`ControlSend`](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm), note that it specifically says:

> Unlike the Send command, mouse clicks cannot be sent by ControlSend. Use ControlClick for that.

`ControlClick` isn’t really meant for sending clicks to a top-level window, so you would have to identify the control(s), and this assumes that the game even uses actual controls.

---

Try the following and change the `SendMode` if necessary (particularly try *Play*)

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Relative           ; Explicitly set mouse coords to relative
SetTitleMatchMode, 1                 ; Match start of titlebar (e.g., Foobar*)
SendMode Event                       ; Use Event mode (try Input and Play)
#IfWinActive, Championship Manager   ; Only make hotkeys for specified window
  F1::Click 42, 191                  ;  Send a mouse-click (left-click)
  F2::Click 558, 191                 ;  …
#IfWinActive                         ; Reset conditional block
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Mediachance's [MultiKeyboard Macros](https://www.mediachance.com/multikeyboard/quickmacro.html) can do this.

[Robotask](https://robotask.com/), too.